# Should I create two scripts or have one with a truth statement?

Tags: load-testing, performance-testing, loadrunner

I have created a script which requires 2 scenarios one going in one path and one going the other. I have stored the vuser id using parameters, converted into an integer, and did an if statement with a modulo function to determine if it's 50% of users etc.

I'm wondering whether this would be more resource heavy on our injector than if I were to create 2 scripts instead of the if statement?

Thanks,

Comment: I don't know much about load testing but it sounds to me you want to have 2 scripts

Answer (score 0):

I believe it shouldn't make much of impact on the injector as long as you are having enough number of Load generators to share the load.

If you want to be very sure about resource impact, you can run a small load test with one with single script and another with two scripts and check the Resource usage of the Load generators using Perfmon ( assuming Windows Server)

Also, instead of using if Statement, you can also use Action Blocks in Run Time Settings and separate two scenarios as 50%-50% , if that helps in debugging any issues later related to the Test case/scenario.